# Cassandra 3.6 returning inconsistent results for simple select query and row count

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

We have 3 node cassandra cluster with cassandra 3.6 installed. Among of them 2 are seeds. `Replication Factor` is `2`.

**Problem:** when i perform `SELECT * FROM mykeyspace.table_name;` it returns different number of records.

Also performing `SELECT COUNT(*) from mykeyspace.table_name;` returns different row counts.

The surprising thing is that everything was working fine till yesterday, don't know what is the cause of issue or whether it is a bug or something else.

We tried `nodetool repair` and restart the cassandra in each node but those things didn't fix the issue.

Comment: check with higher consistency

Comment: I applied CONSISTENCY ALL from cqlsh. Thanx.. It works as expected now.